# Using OOB tag in AIML with Pandorabots

Tags: tags, artificial-intelligence, chatbot, aiml, pandorabots

I'm new to chatbots and I'm trying to use the OOB tag in AIML (OOB stands for “out of band,” which is an engineering term used to refer to activity performed on a separate, hidden channel). I've tried to use it in pandorabots playground, like this:

```
<category>
    <pattern>SEARCH FOR *</pattern>
    <template>Here is what I found on Google. <oob><search><star/></search></oob>
    </template>
</category>
```

So, when talking to the bot:

```
Human: Search for chatbots.
Bot: Here is what I found on Google. <oob><search>chatbots</search></oob>
```

As you can see, I'm also getting the  tag. Is that how it should work? I expect to get it already parsed in some way so I can trigger the web browser in my App!

Maybe I'm wrong and pandora won't parse the  tag for me and I have to do it myself when getting the response?

My idea is to use its API with the /talk resource in my future App.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `oob` tag cannot be used in online hosting. It can only be used along side a local hosting program, and works best on mobile devices. If you want some more info on how to incorporate this tag into VPAs (bots used in the same way as Apple's Siri), look up some info on the "callmom" pandorabots server. (You probably already know all about this, but I'm just making sure.)

PS: You should probably move your post to the AI stack exchange, you may get a lot more, better answers.

Comment: My intention is to use it in my App and trigger specific basic commands related to it, like "go to this section" or "show me this specific product". For this reason, I think I should parse myself the <oob> tag that pandorabot is sending to me as a response and do the custom action/command needed.

Do you think that makes sense this working scenario?

1. Use online hosting (pandorabots) to send the request.
2. Get the response and show it in the chat (without the <oob> tag).
3. Parse the <oob> tag locally in my App.

Comment: Yes, I believe that would make sense, but as I said, you may need to launch  your bot via a non-pandorabots hosting app to be able to parse the <oob> tag.